# Ошибка 404 в Chrome не загружаются картинки

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, frontend

Почему не загружаются картинки в Chrome, Opera и т.д.?
Самое, что удивительное всё работает хорошо в браузере Edge.

**Ошибка:**
GET http://localhost:3000/images/320/gallery_image_1.avif 404 (Not Found)

**Код подключения картинок:**

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="images/320/gallery_image_1.avif 1x, images/320/gallery_image_1@2x.avif 2x, images/320/gallery_image_1@3x.avif 3x" media="(min-width: 6.25em) and (max-width: 26.25em)" type="image/avif">
   <source srcset="images/320/gallery_image_1.webp 1x, images/320/gallery_image_1@2x.webp 2x, images/320/gallery_image_1@3x.webp 3x" media="(min-width: 6.25em) and (max-width: 26.25em)" type="image/webp">
   <source srcset="images/320/gallery_image_1.jpg 1x, images/320/gallery_image_1@2x.jpg 2x, images/320/gallery_image_1@3x.jpg 3x" media="(min-width: 6.25em) and (max-width: 26.25em)">
   <source srcset="images/768/gallery_image_1.avif 1x, images/768/gallery_image_1@2x.avif 2x, images/768/gallery_image_1@3x.avif 3x" media="(min-width: 26.313em) and (max-width: 48em)" type="image/avif">
   <source srcset="images/768/gallery_image_1.webp 1x, images/768/gallery_image_1@2x.webp 2x, images/768/gallery_image_1@3x.webp 3x" media="(min-width: 26.313em) and (max-width: 48em)" type="image/webp">
   <source srcset="images/768/gallery_image_1.jpg 1x, images/768/gallery_image_1@2x.jpg 2x, images/768/gallery_image_1@3x.jpg 3x" media="(min-width: 26.313em) and (max-width: 48em)">
   <source srcset="images/1024/gallery_image_1.avif 1x, images/1024/gallery_image_1@2x.avif 2x, images/1024/gallery_image_1@3x.avif 3x" media="(min-width: 48.063em) and (max-width: 75em)" type="image/avif">
   <source srcset="images/1024/gallery_image_1.webp 1x, images/1024/gallery_image_1@2x.webp 2x, images/1024/gallery_image_1@3x.webp 3x" media="(min-width: 48.063em) and (max-width: 75em)" type="image/webp">
   <source srcset="images/1024/gallery_image_1.jpg 1x, images/1024/gallery_image_1@2x.jpg 2x, images/1024/gallery_image_1@3x.jpg 3x" media="(min-width: 48.063em) and (max-width: 75em)">
   <source srcset="images/1920/gallery_image_1.avif 1x, images/1920/gallery_image_1@2x.avif 2x, images/1920/gallery_image_1@3x.avif 3x" media="(min-width: 75.063em)" type="image/avif">
   <source srcset="images/1920/gallery_image_1.webp 1x, images/1920/gallery_image_1@2x.webp 2x, images/1920/gallery_image_1@3x.webp 3x" media="(min-width: 75.063em)" type="image/webp">
   <img class="slide-gallery__picture" src="images/1920/gallery_image_1.jpg" srcset="images/1920/gallery_image_1@2x.jpg 2x, images/1920/gallery_image_1@3x.jpg 3x" alt="На картине изображен эскиз человека">
</picture>
```

На самом деле таких ошибок около 25 т.к. картинок столько же и все они не загружаются :)
Раньше такого не было, что сейчас случилось непонятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте существование `.avif` файлов.

Edge [не поддерживает](https://caniuse.com/avif) этот формат и пропускает файл. А Chrome и Opera поддерживают, пытаются загрузить несуществующий файл и закономерно получают 404.

[image]

Comment: Получилось исправить ошибку, оказывается в папке у меня нет avif файлов, но я зачем-то их подключал видимо уже на автомате. Спасибо за ответ!